# ImageJ API WaitForUserDialog

Tags: javascript, imagej

I'm trying to write a plugin for ImageJ that will prompt a user to select a rectangular ROI in a region in the image using the rectangular selection tool button built into the menu bar. Here is my code:

```
import ij.*;
import ij.process.*;
import ij.gui.*;
import java.awt.*;
import ij.plugin.*;

public class computeDOP implements PlugIn {

public void run(String arg) {
    IJ.showMessage("DOP Plugin Status","Load Image");       
    ImagePlus imp = IJ.openImage();
    imp.show();
    IJ.showMessage("DOP Plugin Status","Phantom Loaded, Select Rectangle ROI");     

    //Image ROI
    WaitForUserDialog wait = new WaitForUserDialog("Select a Rectangular ROI", "Please press OK when done.");
    wait.show();
    Roi userROI = impPhantom.getRoi();

    //Create a profile plot
    ProfilePlot pPlotPhantom = new ProfilePlot(impPhantom, true);
    double[] phanProfile = pPlotPhantom.getProfile();



}
```

My problem is that the focus shifts to the prompt dialog that appears due to the WaitForUserDialog. Then it won't allow the user to use any of the menu tools built in to ImageJ. My goal is to halt the plugin, and wait for the user to click ok on the dialog box that appears. However, I need my user to be able to use the rectangle selection tool. Should I be looking into some other way to halt my plugin and prompt the user to select an ROI?

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [`WaitForUserDialog#show()` method](https://github.com/imagej/ImageJA/blob/master/src/main/java/ij/gui/WaitForUserDialog.java#L57-63) to make sure the plugin actually waits for user input and continues only after OK was pressed.

Comment: I've edited the code above to respond to this Answer. There was also a typo with the new operator (now fixed). Now my problem is that the code won't allow the user to choose the ROI. All a user can do is click OK in the dialog box that pops up, and the user can't make image selections at all. This is exactly the same problem I originally had.

Comment: I think I need to pause the whole plugin until the user clicks OK on the dialog box, but I'm not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the behavior of `WaitForUserDialog` has changed and that it's not supposed to block access to the image window this way. Many older macros no longer work because of this, and it's not that clear what an easy work-around is (perhaps running the Dialog on its own thread).